# How to compile C++ files generated by google's protobuf compiler on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, perl, gcc, linker

I'm using a Mac. I have a library written in C++, let's call it "wibble", along with its source code. I can compile this source with GCC 4.3 from macports (`g++-mp-4.3`), and can link the resulting library into other stuff as long as I use GCC 4.3.

However, I need to link this into another application (let's call it "blort") which will only load libs compiled with the GCC 4.2 that is bundled with OS X 10.6 (because that's what *it* was built with)

I can, more or less, mess with wibble's `Makefile` however I may please, but blort is a fixed target. I can write whatever code or build scripts to glue them together I may need. There appears to be no way to get wibble to compile on 4.2 (barring a rewrite, which is out of the question), and the guy who wrote it confirms that.

I am not very familiar with the whole build and linking process in C++, having only been handed this integration, and am completely stumped. Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible? If so, how?

In case it matters, what I'm trying to do is call the methods in wibble from Perl via [Inline::CPP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::CPP), but I'm willing to write raw XS if I have to (I've done *that* before, at least). I need to use the system perl so this will easily build and install on other people's machines. :-/

**UPDATE, 2012-03-01, 1**

I am looking into compiling protobufs using the Mac's compiler, and seeing if I can get wibble to compile with the same compiler using that build of protobufs. I will post the results shortly.

**Hrmph** same errors:

```
g++ -Wall -Wno-unused-function -Wno-long-long -pedantic -O3 -I/Users/sscaffid/local/include -L/Users/sscaffid/local/lib -fPIC -std=c++98 -c wire.pb.cc
In file included from /Users/sscaffid/local/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:43,
                 from wire.pb.cc:10:
/Users/sscaffid/local/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.h:94: error: comma at end of enumerator list
/Users/sscaffid/local/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.h:117: error: comma at end of enumerator list
/Users/sscaffid/local/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.h:132: error: comma at end of enumerator list
In file included from wire.pb.cc:10:
/Users/sscaffid/local/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:303: error: extra ‘;’
/Users/sscaffid/local/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:304: error: extra ‘;’
/Users/sscaffid/local/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:305: error: extra ‘;’
/Users/sscaffid/local/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:306: error: extra ‘;’
/Users/sscaffid/local/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:307: error: extra ‘;’
/Users/sscaffid/local/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:308: error: extra ‘;’
In file included from wire.pb.cc:11:
/Users/sscaffid/local/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h:322: error: comma at end of enumerator list
/Users/sscaffid/local/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h:341: error: comma at end of enumerator list
/Users/sscaffid/local/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h:352: error: comma at end of enumerator list
/Users/sscaffid/local/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h:1206: error: extra ‘;’
/Users/sscaffid/local/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h:1223: error: extra ‘;’
/Users/sscaffid/local/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h:1243: error: extra ‘;’
/Users/sscaffid/local/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h:1249: error: extra ‘;’
/Users/sscaffid/local/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h:1257: error: extra ‘;’
/Users/sscaffid/local/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h:1264: error: extra ‘;’
/Users/sscaffid/local/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.h:1274: error: extra ‘;’
In file included from wire.pb.cc:13:
/Users/sscaffid/local/include/google/protobuf/wire_format.h:226: error: comma at end of enumerator list
make: *** [wire.pb.o] Error 1
```

Comment: What's supported in 4.3 that doesn't work in 4.2?  I'm surprised a complete rewrite would be required.  I guess anything is possible with C++.

Comment: I wish I knew for certain. However, it uses google's protobuf APIs and  when I attempt to compile on 4.2, it completely blows up when parsing the protobuf code.

Comment: "completely blows up" is a bit vague - you presumably get some kind of error messages, right?

Comment: Sorry. Code here: (grrr, don't know how to get it to format nicely)

    In file included from /opt/local/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:43,
                 from wire.pb.cc:10:
    /opt/local/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.h:94: error: comma at end of enumerator list
    In file included from wire.pb.cc:10:
    /opt/local/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:303: error: extra ‘;’
    /opt/local/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:304: error: extra ‘;’
    /opt/local/include/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h:305: error: extra ‘;’

Comment: I don't think this needs a complete rewrite, but a simple "fix" to the `enums`: remove the comma after the last value. This is supposed to work, but it seems GCC 4.2 doesn't implement it (correctly). For the other, I'd need to see the code, but there seems to be an optional semicolon that GCC 4.2 again doesn't implement (correctly). Also, don't use `<code>` tags, use the `{}` button at the top to indent code (or hit ctrl-K).

Comment: thank you, I will see what I can do in that direction.

Comment: Thanks to the commenters, I figured out what the *real* problem was. :)

Comment: Right on - got it working now?

Comment: yup! goes to show what needless pedantry gets you!

Comment: @Hercynium Instead of modifying your question to include the answer (and modifying the title to indicate it), please make your solution an actual answer. You are allowed to do so. Then you can later accept it as the solution to your question. This all looks a bit better.

Answer (score -1):

From the question:

## Solution:

Using the `-pedantic` option to GCC 4.2 makes it very angry with `protobuf` code. Don't use it.